# jQuery radiobuttonlist dependencies

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

On my survey page I have a group of radiobuttonlists with identical items all have the same class:

```
           <asp:RadioButtonList ID = "rbFirstList" runat = "server" CssClass= "tbiDiagnosis">
                <asp:ListItem Text = "0. No" Value = "0"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text = "1. Yes, one episode" Value = "1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text = "2. Yes, two episodes" Value = "2"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text = "3. Yes, three episodes" Value = "3"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text = "4. Yes, four episodes" Value = "4"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text = "5. Yes, five or more episodes" Value = "5"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text = "6. Uncertain" Value = "6"></asp:ListItem>

            </asp:RadioButtonList>

           <asp:RadioButtonList ID = "rbSecondList" runat = "server" CssClass= "tbiDiagnosis">
                <asp:ListItem Text = "0. No" Value = "0"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text = "1. Yes, one episode" Value = "1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text = "2. Yes, two episodes" Value = "2"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text = "3. Yes, three episodes" Value = "3"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text = "4. Yes, four episodes" Value = "4"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text = "5. Yes, five or more episodes" Value = "5"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text = "6. Uncertain" Value = "6"></asp:ListItem>

            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I am trying to prevent all radiobuttonlists have "no" selected(value 0), so when I select(click) one of them I need to know what values they all have selected **except the one that I clicked**.

```
      $('.tbiDiagnosis input:radio').click(function(e) {

            if ($(this).val() == 0) {

                //selector is obviously incorrect, how would I do it here?
                if ('.tbiDiagnosis input:checked:not($this)).val() > 0).length == 0)
                    e.preventDefault();   

            }

      });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what your after, perhaps you could explain in more detail what you're after. I think what you're looking for can be achieved by filtering by value attribute `[value='0']` see example below (untested). I hope this helps.

```
$('.tbiDiagnosis input:radio').click(function(e) {

    if ($(this).val() == 0) {
        var checked = $(".tbiDiagnosis input:checked");
        var filtered = checked.not(checked.find("[value='0']"));

         if (filtered.length == 0)
             e.preventDefault();   

     }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, this is what i am after - make sure that at least one of them has selected value other then "0".